# My MacOS Application pops open a java icon

Tags: java, macos

When I try to open my mac application, java icon pops up on the dock and then opens my app. But I want it to open like any other mac application where you click the app and it shouldn't open that separate java application on the dock. [Here's the example of when I click my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEfGr.png)

Furthermore, more info about my app. It's a java application with multiple jar files that I converted into a .app for it to open like an app on mac. It has a jar file that opens the app and has an executable that opens the app as well. So, the only open problem is the extra window to open the application.

Comment: Thats settings from OS. Or you need to export your app in other format than .jar

Comment: I tried with an executable as well. There were many answers that suggested hiding the icon from the dock. But that won't solve my problem, as that java application takes over pretending as the app in use and so if I hide it, I can't access my app

Comment: You cannot set your dock to not combine same apps?

Comment: @raul1ro that's a workaround, not a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I case you have control over the java command that is running the app you could specify `-Dapple.awt.UIElement=true` as a start option.
This should suppress the icon from appearing.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know what you mean by "have control over the java command that is running the app". Also where would I specify that?

Comment: Could you describe a bit more what you meant with "multiple jar files that I converted into a .app" in the question?

Comment: Well initially the app would only open when clicked on the executable. I added the property list and hierarchy so that it would work like a regular mac application. Basically .app in the sense that you can open it now by clicking the .app.

Comment: I'm more interessted in the build/bundling process: how get the jar bundled to an app?

Comment: I didn't bundle. Rather I navigated path to access the jar files. So I change the classpath so that it accessed the jar files in the resources files of an app. I am not sure that answers your question.

Comment: As of 2023 this is still the only solution that works (if you cannot compile the app yourself). Be aware that it will also suppress the 'running' dot indicator below the icon.